# fillRect not showing up

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I have a problem with drawing a rect on screen. I have the paintComponent method in my jpanel class and I want to draw a rect in it. It looks like this:

```
public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {

    super.paintComponent( g );

    g.setColor( Color.yellow );
    g.fillRect( 0, 140, 100, 100 );

}
```

The problem is that I have a couple of panels added to the one that I'm drawing in. The subpanels always show up on top and the rect is drawn beneath them. How can I make it so that the rect is drawn in front?

Answer (score 4):

If the drawn JPanel is in the container, then there's no way that it can be in "front". You can make the child components non-opaque by calling `setOpaque(false)` on them, but still the container will always be behind its children.

If you absolutely want a component above another, consider using a JLayeredPane or consider drawing on the top level window's glass pane.

Answer (score 3):

No offense, but I feel this is a bad idea...

```
public void paint( Graphics g ) {

    super.paint( g );

    g.setColor( Color.yellow );
    g.fillRect( 0, 140, 100, 100 );

}
```

As Hovercraft has pointed out, a better approach would be to use a `GlassPane` ([How to use RootPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)) or a `JLayeredPane` or [`JLayer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) (AKA `JXLayer` if you're not using Java 7)